# Postgres: How to set column default value as another column value while altering the table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgres table with millions of record in it. Now I want to add new column to that table called "time_modified" with the value in another column  "last_event_time". Running a migration script is taking long time , so need a simple solution to run in production.

Comment: There is no "simple" solution. The only way is to run an `update` after you have added the column.

Comment: do you affraid block table for others process ?

Comment: Can not afford to lock the table for long duration as db is critical for client apps

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the columns are timestamps you can try:

```
alter table my_table add time_modified text;
alter table my_table alter time_modified type timestamp using last_event_time;
```

Comment: Wouldn't an update be more efficient? The `alter table` uses an exclusive lock on the table while an update would at least allow selecting from it while the update is running.

Comment: It depends on server load and other clients. Once we obtain a lock the operation should be much faster than an update. I would do this on Sunday at 4 am ;)

Comment: Thanks klin .This solution better than update but only concern about locking the table. Is there any better option ?

Comment: I don't think there is a better solution. You have to choose between locking all rows for write and an exclusive lock on the table, and it depends on the current server load. I think the key is to choose the right moment.

Comment: If the server is permanently heavily loaded, you can perform updates in chunks. Of course, these partial updates have to be executed in their own transactions (not all in a single transaction).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use function with `pg_sleep`, which wait between iteriation in loop

This way don't invoke exclusive lock and others locks on your_table.

> SELECT pg_sleep(seconds);

But time of execute is long

```
alter table my_table add time_modified timestamp;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_mew_column()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    rec record;

BEGIN
    for rec in (select id,last_event_time from your_table) loop

        update your_table set time_modified = rec.last_event_time where id = rec.id;
        PERFORM pg_sleep(0.01);

    end loop;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

and execute function:

```
select update_mew_column();
```

Comment: This will simply increase the time the locks are held.